# Multidimensional array in java, printing out a frame

Tags: arrays, printing, multidimensional-array, constants, frame

my question is, how can i make an multidimensional array, that is visually a frame made out of '*' symbols, just like in the image below.

In my assignment i have 2 constants - Widht and Height of the frame.
How can i make the array appear like that, without having to put for every empty space in the array a '*'.

http://imageshack.us/a/img24/5600/ib0x.jpg

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE ALREADY:

```
public class UpravljalnikOken{
public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 15;
public static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 15;
//public static final int NAJVECJE_ST_OKEN = 5;

public static void main (String[]args){
    char [] [] okvir = new char [FRAME_HEIGHT] [FRAME_WIDTH];

    okvir [0][0] = '*';
    okvir [0][1] = '*';
    okvir [0][2] = '*';
    okvir [0][3] = '*';
    okvir [0][4] = '*';
    okvir [0][5] = '*';
    okvir [1][0] = '*';
    okvir [2][0] = '*';
    okvir [3][0] = '*';
    okvir [4][0] = '*';
    okvir [5][0] = '*';
    okvir [6][0] = '*';
    // ...….. is this the only way? 

display(okvir);
}
public static void display(char x[][]){
    for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++){
        for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
            System.out.print(x[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

am i going into the right direction? Or is there an easier way?
Thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the array using 2 for loops, then a simple if statement to limit the '*' you want to print in the middle of the box (r = row, c = column). Also the name of your class seems a little but too random, a name such as ArrayPractice, or StarBox even would be more descriptive.

```
   for (int r = 0; r < okvir.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < okvir[c].length; c++) {
            // Only the first and the last line should be all '*'
            if (r > 1 && r < FRAME_HEIGHT - 2) {
                okvir[r][0] = '*';
                okvir[r][FRAME_WIDTH - 1] = '*';
            }
            else {
                okvir[r][c] = '*';  
            }
        } // end for
    } // end for
```